# Using admin email in billing address

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, email

My payment processor sends payment confirmation email to customers with my legal entity's name on it. Problem is my legal entity's name is different from the domain name so it creates confusion after customers receive payment confirmation email. I want to set **admin email** as the billing email when information is being passed to the payment processor from checkout page, however, customer should receive order confirmation email from my woocommerce store on their billing email.

Is it possible to fix admin email as billing email while passing Full Name, Email & Phone # to payment processor, but send order confirmation email to email entered by the customer?

I checked into payment processor's plugin and I think something here needs to be changed but I don't know what because I'm a novice in woocommerce and a beginner in coding.

Here's the code from payment processor's plugin:

```
public function getCustomerInfo($order)
    {
        if (version_compare(WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION, '2.7.0', '>='))
        {
            $args = array(
                'name'    => $order->get_billing_first_name() . ' ' . $order->get_billing_last_name(),
                'email'   => $order->get_billing_email(),
                'contact' => $order->get_billing_phone(),
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $args = array(
                'name'    => $order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $order->billing_last_name,
                'email'   => $order->billing_email,
                'contact' => $order->billing_phone,
            );
        }

        return $args;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! Please note that  WooCommerce is [offtopic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, you can ask on [so].

Comment: Have you check woo-commerce setting  Email option i think from there you can set  update changes easily